# Words that are synonyms to 'to put one’s foot in one’s mouth'?

Tags: meaning, word-request, synonyms

What words are there that have a similar meaning to  'put one’s foot in one’s mouth'?

Comment: Faux pas?  Or are you looking for single words only?

Comment: @stevekeiretsu what else? please show more words

Comment: Most of the offerings [here](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/misspeak) have at least some overlap -- gaffe, goof, misspeak, blunder, tactlessness, etc, although I don't know if any capture the idiom exactly - that's why idioms exist after all.